# Question on the labelling of coefficients in the expression ( as a linear combination) of the image of a basis vector under a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, soft-question

Source : Garrity, *All the Mathematics You Missed* [ screenshot below, passage highlighted in image no.2 ]

The question I am asking deals with a passage of the above book where the author aims at showing that a linear transformation from a vector space $V$ ( with basis $\{v_1 ... v_n\}$) to a vector space $W$ ( with basis $\{v_1 ... v_m\}$) can be represented as an  $m \times n$ matrix.

It has previously be shown that $V$ can be represented as a set of column vectors in $R^n$ and that $W$ can be represented as a set of column vectors in $R^m$ , as follows :

[image]

Now, he author states that, since, by hypothesis, we have a linear transformation $T$  from $V$ to $W$  :

> For each basis vector $v_i$  in $V$ , $T(v_i)$ will be a vector in $W$
> . Thus there will exist real numbers $a_{1i}, ... , a_{mi}$ such that
> :
>
> $$\Large T(v_i) = a_{1i} w_1 + .... + a_{mi} w_m$$

I understand why $T(v_i)$ will be in $W$ by the definition of function $T$.

I also understand why $T(v_i)$ , being a member of $W$,  can be expressed as a linear combinaton of the basis vectors of $W$ , that is of $w_1$ , $w_2$, all the way down to $w_m$.

> **What I do not get is the way the coefficients ( $a_{1i} ... a_{mi}$ )
> are labelled**.

I see that the subscripts are specially chosen to match the matrix notation, but this seems so to say "ad hoc" ( since the goal is to represent transformation $T$ as a matrix).

Also, since the author has chosen ( before this passage) to represent the vectors of $W$ as column vectors in $R^m$ and to use $b_1 ... b_m$ to denote the elements of these column vectors, should not $T(v_i)\in W$ be expressed with $b$ coefficients?

The title of the book was not lying : I am missing something here !

[image]

Comment: $a_i$ and $b_i$ are not important. It is just a notation. If $v = 3v_1 + 2v_2$ and if $v = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2$ then $a_1 = 3$ and $a_2 = 2$. In the same way, if $v = 3v_1 + 2v_2$ and if $v = b_1 v_1 + b_2 v_2$ then $b_1 = 3$ and $b_2 = 2$.